# Windows IoT could not attach to remote python debugging session

Tags: python, visual-studio, raspberry-pi, windowsiot, raspberry-pi3

I try to write the Hello World example (python) in Visual Studio for raspberry pi 3 (Insider Build). I did every step form https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/Python.htm but if I press F5 Visual Studio freezes and after 3-5 mins the message "could not attach to remote python debugging session" appears. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It should be the problem with the msvsmon or SD card - most of the debugging issues i saw were related to that. Could you try:

1) Another SD card (ideally - from the supported on the Hardware page https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/SupportedInterfaces.htm

2) schtasks /run /th StartMsVsmon

What is the version of the software you are using?

---

If that is the helpful answer, please mark it as a helpful or as the answer. Thanks!